# No puedo obtener un solo documento

Tags: angular, firebase, typescript

Actualmente estoy haciendo un proyecto con angular y firebase, el problema es que cuando quiero obtener un solo documento en el momento en que aparece el archivo console.log del componente, me devuelve indefinido.  Este es el código del servicio:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Product } from '../interfaces/Product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ConexionService {
  private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Product>;
  private items: Observable<Product[]>;
    private itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Item>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<Product>('Products');
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map((actions) =>
        actions.map((a) => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Product;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        })
      )
    );
  }
listItem() {
    return this.items;
  }

  getOne(id: string): any {
    this.afs
      .collection<Product>('Products')
      .doc(id)
      .ref.get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          console.log(doc.data());
          return doc.data();
        } else {
          return 'Doc does not exits';
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
}
```

Y este es el código del componente

```
constructor(private _service: ConexionService){
     console.log('from component-', this._service.getOne('data_1'));
}
```

Esta es la salida de la consola:

> from component-undefined

Creo que el problema es que se llama a la función antes de que se optengan los datos de Firebase, pero no sé cómo resolverlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás tratando un bloque de ejecución asíncrono entonces cuando intentas obtener un valor del método getOne la promesa no está resuelta, y además el método no tiene ningún valor de retorno, solamente la promesa.

Tienes dos opciones:

**OPCIÓN A**

1. Retornas la promesa y ejecutas el then en el componente (no la recomiendo)

**OPCIÓN B**

1. Creas un BehaviorSubject en el servicio (selectedDocSubject) y llamas igual al método getOne sin embargo no lo asignas a nada, ya que el método solo se encargará de hacer el llamado asíncrono a firebase.
2. Cuando la promesa se resuelve, vamos a ejecutar un .next en el behavior subject para enviar un nuevo valor en el flujo, si el objeto existe enviamos el objeto y sino enviamos nulo.
3. Vamos a tener también un método llamado getSelectedProduct que va a retornar un observable, este lo puedes obtener en el componente y suscribirte (o mejor aún usar async pipe para obtener el valor en la plantilla)

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreCollection,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Product } from '../interfaces/Product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ConexionService {
  private itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Product>;
  private items: Observable<Product[]>;
  private itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Item>;
  private selectedDocSubject: BehaviorSubject<Product | null>

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.selectedDocSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Product>(null)
    this.itemsCollection = afs.collection<Product>('Products');
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map((actions) =>
        actions.map((a) => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Product;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        })
      )
    );
  }
listItem() {
    return this.items;
  }
  
  // Vamos a retornar el BehaviorSubject como un observable para que
  // el componente no sea capaz de ejecutar un .next() sino solamente
  // de suscribirse.
  getSelectedProduct(): Observable<Product | null> {
    return this.selectedProductSubject.asObservable()
  }

  getOne(id: string): any {
    this.afs
      .collection<Product>('Products')
      .doc(id)
      .ref.get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
         this.selectedProductSubject.next(doc)
        } else {
          // Este mensaje lo puedes manejar en el componente en caso de que el selectedProduct este nulo
           this.selectedProductSubject.next(null)
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
}
```